# Django (v1.11.3) UnorderedObjectListWarning even though list is ordered

Tags: python, django

I keep running into Django's `UnorderedObjectListWarning` when trying to display model instances in a paginated view for search results. However, there is a default ordering defined in the models.py file:

```
class Rfc(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='RFC'
        verbose_name_plural='RFCs'
        ordering=['number']
```

The actual search happens in views.py and is defined as follows:

```
# parse GET parameters
search_term = request.GET.get('q', '')
category = request.GET.get('c', 'cs')
page = request.GET.get('p', 1)

...

results_rfc = Rfc.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=search_term) | Q(number__icontains=search_term)
)

if category=='cs':
    active_tab = 'cs'
    results = results_cs
else:
    active_tab = 'rfc'
    results = results_rfc

paginator = Paginator(results, 15)
```

However, I cannot seem to make it work, even when explicitly telling Django to `order_by('number')` in the filter function above. The result is always:

```
UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'directory.models.Rfc'> QuerySet.
paginator = Paginator(results, 15)
```

What baffles me even more is that this warning is not displayed when executing above code in `manage.py shell`. Clearly, I am missing something here. Any ideas?

Comment: first of all where is results_cs? do you have it or not?

Comment: yes, located where I put the "...". It's just a way bigger function call and I thought it might distract here.

Comment: which condition is getting passed to the paginator?

Comment: definitely 'results_rfc'. Plus, it wouldn't complain about <class 'directory.models.Rfc'> in the warning text I figure, since under an alternative condition, another model is searched.

Comment: remove the ordering from the meta where you have given number

Comment: same result. I removed the Meta field and then tried it with and without the explicit `order_by` in views.py, but nothing changed.

Comment: did you ran makemigrations and migrate after removing the field?

Comment: yes, ran both commands

Comment: what type of data is there in numbeR?

Comment: it's an IntegerField. also, it's the models primary_key, if that is relevant

Comment: and what type of search term are you passing? that matches title? which i guess contains characters only?then why the or portion for the number?

Comment: well, I'm searching for RFC documents, hence both and title and number are of interest. in [this example](https://imgur.com/a/GnO3O) I'm searching for a term in the document's title. It does find the right results but pagination is still screwed up, since there are only 5 results but 353 pages displayed.

Comment: Class meta should be nested to model class. In your sample it isn't.

Comment: oops, that happened when pasting the code in here (fixed it now). it is nested in my models.py. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Possibly it's because you use `Q` objects.

Comment: Also, how did you try to apply `order_by` in the view? According to the documentation, using `order_by` should set the QuerySet property `ordered` to `True`, which would prevent the warning. Did you try something like this? `paginator = Paginator(results.order_by('number'), 15)`

Comment: Can you write a debug statement in your view to confirm that `assert Rfc.objects.all().ordered == True` and also `assert results.ordered == False` before you pass it to the paginator? That could help figure out where the query set became unordered, or if it was unordered in the first place for some reason.

Comment: Oh wow.. the hint to writing the assertion led me to the actual error, when none of my debug variables showed up on the web page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.. so this is embarrassing: turns out that yes indeed, the object_list was sorted all along, but there was a copy of a faulty, older version of the view function at the bottom of the file, which of cause overwrote the first one's results.